# Android Custom Keyboard with custom keys (words in keypress)

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to create keyboard with my own keys. I do learned how to make a qwerty keyboard and now I changed layout suiting my keyboard.

But I want to add words in a single key press, Is it possible?

```
<Key android: codes="104 101 108 108 111" android: keyLabel="h" />
```

like this, where keypress 'h' types "hello" other than the single key also I want to add DONE (-4) button in the last position to send the text. 
With commas it comes optional keys[h/e/l/l/o]. and the above code is error because of space. 
Any help. 
Reference: https://github.com/tutsplus/Android-CustomKeyboard
just edited qwerty.xml to set my design, and now stuck with this.

Comment: Easiest way to do it is to just not use KeyboardView.  Then you can draw any keys and make them input any data you want.  There's no requirement to use it (and none of the major keyboards do).

Comment: But I made the layout and waiting for a way to put the code in there. And I just know how to built a keyboard for now (that codes even copied and edited by me from a online tutorial blog), So could be useful if anyone can help me with this 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have prepared the keyboard by extending [InputMethodService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html) which is the standard way of doing so.

For the example you cited ,the file [SimpleIME.java](https://github.com/tutsplus/Android-CustomKeyboard/blob/master/SimpleKeyboard/src/com/hathy/simplekeyboard/SimpleIME.java) has the function

> public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {

You need to add your keycode case inside

> switch(primaryCode){

and handle like this :

```
CharSequence text = "your text here";
InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
if (ic != null) {
    ic.commitText(text, 1);
}
```

Hope that helps~

Comment: I have just edited the qwerty.xml file of a tutorial on how to make keyboard. in the method.xml 
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    > 
     <subtype
  android:label="@string/subtype_en_US"  
  android:imeSubtypeLocale="en_US"
  android:imeSubtypeMode="keyboard" />
</input-method```

 should I have to change the edit here?

Comment: I edited the reply according to the code you referred to make your keyboard. Should work :)

Comment: No. Path is : Android-CustomKeyboard / SimpleKeyboard / src / com / hathy / simplekeyboard / SimpleIME.java

Comment: hastebin.com/ejayivivik

Comment: or just a the type me case for entering #!adv and to send that. 

Comment: that's so nice of you

Comment: then to send #!adv on keypress, (posting on my question)

Comment: just add a key in layout with some arbitrary android:codes value and edit CharSequence text = "#!adv"; in the code modified by me. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer :D

Comment: case name should be like? i just thought i can put any name

Comment: You can declare an int variable with keycode declared by you in layout and use that variable name in switch case.

Comment: mind if i ask your Hangouts email id for this.  or github

Comment: Add this <Key android: codes="999" android: keyLabel="#! adv" /> to your layout and use this code value in switch as I told. This should be simple enough

Comment: but i didn't declared 999 anywhere

Comment: 999 is just some arbitrary code. You can add any integer.

Comment: i didn't yet add that switch command because i don't got how to declare the case  "this name";

Comment: You know switch case right? Or just add case 999: and my code

Comment: yep. so case 999 it is?

Comment: No. Why should it be "name"? You have to check the case which has code same as the one you added in layout. So 999 it should be. Try and let me know.

Comment: is it possible to add that enter key code with it

Comment: sure.. but it saying need 15 reputation something ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Anyway to do enter key after typing the text too.  

Comment: String text = "your text" + System.lineSeparator();

Comment: which is with the previous key only. on case 999

Comment: Yes the same case

Comment: so CharSequence text changes to String text ?

Comment: Btw, Most apps use enter key as next line.

Comment: Is it possible to make it as like send button itself

Comment: Buddy. You need to work on things yourself also. Try experimenting with stuff. It will widen your knowledge. You should raise another question when you have substantially different queries from the original post. You can change the android:keyLabel = "Send" so it will do your task and appear as send button.

Comment: Am rush to finish this.. Am very thankful to you btw.

Comment: One last on this post, keySend where should I declare. It pushes an error

Comment: Add this <Key android: codes="999" android: keyLabel="Send" />

Comment: but I do want to label it as ADV only.. may be open a new post